# Filtering 2D Arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array, filter

Using Excel and VBA, I wanted some advice on how to best filter data in an array (in the same sort of way one might use a pivot table) strictly using VBA.  I am creating a UserForm that is going to make some data decisions based on currently existing data. I can visualize how to do it well enough but am not that versed in VBA programming.

Here is an example

```
A       B       C
bob     12      Small
sam     16      Large
sally   1346    Large
sam     13      Small
sally   65      Medium
bob     1       Medium
```

To grab the data in an Array, I could use

```
Dim my_array As Variant

my_array = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

Now, I am familiar with looping through 2D arrays, but I wondered: **what the most effective way to filter 2D array data** (without looping through the array time and again)?

For example, how do I get would be to say get this kind of data:

```
data_for_sally As Variant 'rows with sally as name in ColA
data_for_sally_less_than_ten As Variant ' all rows with sally's name in ColA and colB < 10
data_for_all_mediums as Variant ' all rows where ColC is Medium
```

Suggestions?  I could work this out with a bunch of custom functions and loops but I thought there must be a better way.  Thanks.

Comment: Note that the 4th example is not a filter but an operation on the array, which would probably lead to a different answer.

Comment: Not sure it's possible without looping / custom functions in VBA. You say you have experience in other languages, have you considered a VSTO/.NET impementation then use LINQ?

Comment: For this type of thing in VBA I would use a disconnected ADO recordset.  It gives you sorting and filtering.

Comment: @assylias good point, removed that example; .@lori_m i was thinking along the lines of Python, actually; .@Tim Williams i will have to look into that, haven't heard of it before.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you want to use VBA only.

I think it depends on several parameters, mainly on:

- how often you run the same condition => do you store the result of a filter or do you recalculate every time?
- how often you need to filter stuff => if often, it is worth having a proper code structure in place, if not then a one off loop is clearly the way to go.

From an OO perspective, assuming performance (speed & memory) is not an issue, I would go for the following design (I won't go into the details of the implementation, only give the general idea). Create a class (let's call it imaginatively ArrayFilter) that you could use like this.

**Setup the filter**

```
Dim filter As New ArrayFilter
With filter
    .name = "sam"
    .category = "Medium"
    .maxValue = 10
End With
```

Or

```
filter.add(1, "sam") 'column 1
filter.add(3, "Medium") 'column 3
filter.addMax(2, 10) 'column 2
```

**Create the filtered data set**

```
filteredArray = getFilteredArray(originalArray, filter)
```

The getFilteredArray is fairly straightforward to write: you loop over the array checking if the values match the filter and put the valid lines in a new array:

```
If filter.isValidLine(originalArray, lineNumber) Then 'append to new array
```

**Pros**

- Clean design
- Reusable, especially with the second version where you use the column number. This can be used to filter any arrays really.
- Filtering code is in one function that you can test
- Corollary: avoid duplication of code

**Cons**

- Filtering is recalculated every time, even if you use the same filter twice. You can store the results in a Dictionary for example - see below.
- Memory: every call to the getFilteredArray creates a new array, but not sure how this can be avoided anyway
- This adds quite a few lines of code, so I would do it only if it helps make the code easier to read / maintain.

ps: If you need to cache the results to improve performance, one way would be to store the results in a dictionary and add some logic to the getFilteredArray function. Note that unless your arrays are really big and/or you run the same filter a lot, this is probably not worth it.

```
filters.add filter, filteredArray 'filters is a dictionary
```

That way, when you call getFilteredArray  next time, you can do something like this:

```
For each f in filters
    'Check if all conditions in f and newFilter are the same
    'If they are:
    getFilteredArray = filters(f)
    Exit Function
Next

'Not found in cache: compute the result
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach - I was hoping that VBA had something built in I could use on the fly.  But, re-using an OO approach may have to be the next best thing.  Thanks for the detailed reply.  Will have to try it out.

Comment: Rereading it, getFilteredArray should probably be a function inside the ArrayFilter class.

Comment: What is full form of OO?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
' credited to ndu
Function Filter2DArray(ByVal sArray, ByVal ColIndex As Long, ByVal FindStr As String, ByVal HasTitle As Boolean)
  Dim tmpArr, i As Long, j As Long, Arr, Dic, TmpStr, Tmp, Chk As Boolean, TmpVal As Double
  On Error Resume Next
  Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  tmpArr = sArray
  ColIndex = ColIndex + LBound(tmpArr, 2) - 1
  Chk = (InStr("><=", Left(FindStr, 1)) > 0)
  For i = LBound(tmpArr, 1) - HasTitle To UBound(tmpArr, 1)
    If Chk Then
      TmpVal = CDbl(tmpArr(i, ColIndex))
      If Evaluate(TmpVal & FindStr) Then Dic.Add i, ""
    Else
      If UCase(tmpArr(i, ColIndex)) Like UCase(FindStr) Then Dic.Add i, "" 'This finds only exact matches, if you need *FindStr* use:  If UCase(tmpArr(i, ColIndex)) Like UCase("*" & FindStr & "*") Then Dic.Add i, ""

    End If
  Next
  If Dic.Count > 0 Then
    Tmp = Dic.Keys
    ReDim Arr(LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(Tmp) + LBound(tmpArr, 1) - HasTitle, LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2))
    For i = LBound(tmpArr, 1) - HasTitle To UBound(Tmp) + LBound(tmpArr, 1) - HasTitle
      For j = LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2)
        Arr(i, j) = tmpArr(Tmp(i - LBound(tmpArr, 1) + HasTitle), j)
      Next
    Next
    If HasTitle Then
      For j = LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2)
        Arr(LBound(tmpArr, 1), j) = tmpArr(LBound(tmpArr, 1), j)
      Next
    End If
  End If
  Filter2DArray = Arr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this today.
My solution was similar to the one posted by @assylias, in that I also create a new array with the applied filters for processing.

There are other ways of doing this (like transpose & preserve), but this method allows you to execute the filter using only one redim, and no loss of data on the original array.

It works best if your input data has already been sorted, as unless you create an additional index field you wont be able to locate the locations in the input array to do operations directly on those items.

Note that in this example the input array was created from a  `listobject.databodyrange`

```
Private Function FilterArray(aInput As Variant, FCriteria As String, aInputColCount) Variant

Dim i as integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim fArray() As Variant
Dim RowCount As Integer

'Validate the input array
If Not IsArray(aInput) Then
   Debug.Print ("Error: Input to Function[FilterArray] is not an array") & vbNewLine
   Exit Function
End If

'count the number of records that match the search criteria in the input array, here I use the 13th column.
RowCount = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(aInput) 
    If aInput(i, 13) = FCriteria Then: RowCount = RowCount + 1
Next

'define the array size for your filtered array.
ReDim fArray(1 To RowCount, 1 To aInputColCount) As Variant

k = 1
For i = 1 To ubound(aInput)
    If aInput(i, 13) = FCriteria Then
    'populate a row in your filtered array
       For j = 1 To aInputColCount 
          fArray(k, j) = aInput(i, j)
          k = k + 1
       Next j
     End If 
Next i

FilterArray = fArray

End Function
```