# 2D array FIlter - VBA NO EXCEL

Tags: arrays, vba, 2d

in this post [Filtering 2D Arrays in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450645/filtering-2d-arrays-in-excel-vba) several years ago it had been proposed a function for 2D array filter, but using an excel function :

```
If Evaluate(TmpVal & FindStr) Then Dic.Add i, ""
```

Now Evaluate it's not available on VBA for my application Autodesk.
Please somebody could suggest me how to substitute it ?
I have a bi-dimensional array of two objects properties, tied.
Sometimes object could have same properties see example below

Object 1 Layer "GREEN" length 100

Object 2 Layer "GREEN" length 100

Object 3 Layer "GREEN" length 150

Object 4 Layer "BLUE" length 200

Count Results:

Layer BLUE Length 200 Count 1

Layer GREEN Length 100 Count 2

Layer GREEN Length 150 Count 1

So my scope is to have a bidimensional array with above result.
Filter function unfortunately it works only with one-dimension array.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, I wrote [`stdLambda`](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdLambda.cls) which is a good alternative to `Evaluate()` method

```
for i = lbound(v,1) to ubound(v,1)
  if stdLambda.Create("$1 = """ & sValueName & """")(v(i,iField)) then Dic.Add i, ""
next
```